# How do I open GNOME Tweak Tool from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-tweak-tool

I'm trying the live CD as I am a new user. From the terminal, I have installed gnome tweak tool. After I had installed it, I wasn't able to find any icon to open the program. When I opened Ubuntu software center and searched for advanced settings, I found that it's installed but I can't open it.

Is there any method to open it from GUI or through a command in terminal ?

Comment: They made a dash for you where you can search for everything. Press the windows key or click the big icon on the top left with the ubuntu logo, and type in the name of the application. In a terminal, you can just type the first letters of the name of the application, usually the same as the package name (firefox, nautilus ..) and press the tab key twice. It will list all applications starting with those letters.

Answer (score 16):

Once gnome-tweak-tools is installed, you can run it from the terminal writing:

```
gnome-tweaks
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't have that installed, but it looks as if the command is `gnome-tweak-tool`.

**Update:** Also found more info [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/10/install-gnome-tweak-tool-in-ubuntu-1110.html)

> When installation complete, GNOME Tweak Tool should show up as "Advanced Settings" in the menu. Besides changing fonts or themes, GNOME Tweak Tool can also be used to disable/enable GNOME Shell extensions, tweak the desktop, various windows behavior or GNOME Shell.

Answer (score 2):

> Installing Programs or Other Packages
>
> You can install programs to a LiveCD session in the normal way,
>   although these will be forgotten as soon as you switch the machine
>   off. For example, you might install antivirus or data-recovery tools
>   to fix the system installed on the computer's hard drive. Because
>   space is limited on a LiveCD, you should limit the number of packages
>   you install or consider using a persistent image.

Found it here[help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)

so i am not really sure if you can run this program in a live session. Although you can try opening a terminal [ Control+Alt+T] and then type

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

and hit enter.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have issue running the application.
It may be Python-dependent. Have you seen this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1909933

Btw, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> should be the run prompt (gnome-tweak-tool) && also you should be able to start Gnome Tweak Tool from *Applications –> Other–> Advanced Settings*

P.S.
I'm still unable to answer questions as a comment - or whatever it is, that people add under the question; not sure if that's a feature that comes with reputation, or if I'm missing something :f

Comment: Good use of ubuntuforums, and yes commenting on questions becomes available after you reach 50+ reputation.